# file_get_contents giving error Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that is throwing an error when execute it.

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\Apache24\htdocs\image\test2.php on line 68`
>
> Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\Apache24\htdocs\image\test2.php on line 72`

Basically the script display images from rss feed, but the problem is not displaying all the images only some of them.

Here is the script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$url = "http://www.sahafah.net/rss.php";

$rss = file_get_contents($url);

ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', "none");
$rss1= mb_convert_encoding($rss, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$rss3 = simplexml_load_string($rss1);
if($rss3)
{
    $items = $rss3->channel->item;
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $title = $item->title;
        $link = $item->link;
        $published_on = $item->pubDate;
        $description = $item->description;
        $category = $item->category;
        $guid = $item->guid;
        
        $string2 = $item->description;
        preg_match('/http.*.jpg/',$string2,$match2);
        $convert = implode(",", $match2);
        
        // Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
        $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($convert));
        
        // Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
        $src = 'data: '.exif_imagetype($convert).';base64,'.$imageData;
        
        // Echo out a sample image
        echo '<img src="', $src, '">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is line 68 & 72? Whenever I get errors during my lunch I check the lines but without the numbers may as well go back to my sandwich

Comment: I can guess but its helpful to show the line. Obviously your $convert doesn't have a file at the end of it. Capture $convert when file_get_contents returns false and inspect it to confirm their ain't no file at the end

Comment: @Mike Miller here is the line, line 68 `$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($convert));` and line 72 `$src = 'data: '.exif_imagetype($convert).';base64,'.$imageData;`

Comment: "$convert = implode(",", $match2);" - you are clearly assembling an array here, of course php can't find that filename..

Comment: @ Zencode.dk, i have to convert from array to string thats why im using `$convert = implode(",", $match2);`

Comment: Add a if( file_exists( $convert) ) check before both image calls. I'd debug source data to see why it's missing some images. var_dump with pres and a die on $string2 and $match 2 right above the preg_match

Comment: @Mike Miller if i `echo "$convert";` i can see url link. how come its empty?? im wondering. can you fix my code. please...

Comment: You aren't checking whether preg_match() is successful or not. Since you aren't using any parens in your regex, just say `$convert = $match2[0];` rather than messing with the `implode()` business. But your real problem is your `$item->description` does not have text matching the regex.

Comment: @ Peter Bowers, i use `implode()` to convert from array to string,and `preg_match() ` its returning http url, so its working im ably to extract from `$item->description` urls links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a lot of PHP questions the answer is there isnt actually anything wrong with your code. What you are seeing is not an error its a warning and these would be suppressed in production and your code will work just fine. Fixing warnings/notices is an issue of good practice and really down to you whether you bother. However if you want to get rid of them you can wrap any use of file_get_contents with:

```
if(file_exists($convert)){

    // Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
    $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($convert));

    // Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
    $src = 'data: '.exif_imagetype($convert).';base64,'.$imageData;

    // Echo out a sample image
    echo '<img src="', $src, '">';

}
```

Alternatively if you dont care about warnings and notices you can just do the following at the top of your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

This will mean that the only stuff printed to screen will be actual errors and you wont have to be disturbed by warnings and notices.

Comment: Then the file you are trying to get is returning false to file_exists() - this is expected as you were getting the warning that the file doesn't exist. All evidence point to the file not existing

Comment: Can you share a path for one of them?

Comment: thank you  Mike Mille, i fixed my code instead of `file_exists` i used `if(!empty($convert))` and my code worked smoothly, it was your idea.thank you again....

Comment: As long as its working for you thats good. I would be wary of the test you are using though as if $convert contains ANYTHING it will pass that test but wont have a valid file url for file_get_contents(); However it wont kill you code so probably not worth the tears